# Cannot access class variable to print as it is NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class such as:

```
class MP3:
    name = ""
    capacity = 0
    def newMP3(name, capacity):
        MP3.name = name
        MP3.capacity = capacity
```

My main script:

```
from mp3class import *
currentMP3 = MP3.newMP3("myName", 10)
print (currentMP3.name)
print (currentMP3.capacity)
```

However, the print statements return an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Why is `currentMP3 == None` when I've just assigned it?

I've tried `return (name, capacity)` at the end of `class MP3` and that gives me a different error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Even though the tuple does have `name` in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning `None` implicitly after calling:

```
def newMP3(name, capacity):
    MP3.name = name
    MP3.capacity = capacity
```

and assigning it to the name `currentMP3`.

You're either looking for `__init__` to initialize a new instance with some attributes:

```
def __init__(self, name, capacity):
    self.name = name
    self.capacity = capacity
```

or, as an alternative, you can change the class attributes directly and then create a new instance with `@classmethod`:

```
@classmethod
def newMP3(cls, name, capacity):
    cls.name = name
    cls.capacity = capacity
    return cls()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `newMP3` method in your class doesn't return anything. In Python, that's the same as returning `None`. So when you do `currentMP3 = MP3.newMP3(...)`, `currentMP3` becomes `None` and doesn't have access to the class attributes you set on the `MP3` class.

Note that your use of class attributes and no instances is a very odd one. I'd expect lots of other bugs if you keep going that route. A much more natural implementation would create an instance of the `MP3` class and set attributes on the instance.